# How can I get Orientation Scale Position information of keypoints in OPENCV implementation?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, keypoint

I only can get image features form MAT file, but I also want some other information such as positions, orientation and scale. How can I get these information, could anyone offer its code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of feature detection is a `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>`, where every keypoint contain:

- `Point2f pt`: coordinates of the keypoint
- `float size`: diameter of the meaningful keypoint neighborhood
- `float angle`: computed orientation of the keypoint (-1 if not applicable). Its possible values are in a range [0,360) degrees. It is measured relative to image coordinate system (y-axis is directed downward), ie in clockwise.
- `float response`: the response by which the most strong keypoints have been selected. Can be used for further sorting or subsampling
- `int octave`: octave (pyramid layer) from which the keypoint has been extracted
- `int class_id`: object id that can be used to clustered keypoints by an object they belong to

Comment: Thank you, I am a new beginner of OPENCV. I thought these are included in MAT file.

Comment: what kind of MAT file? [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection) is a tutorial about feature detection, it reads two images into two `cv::Mat`'s, detects feature points over them and finally draws the points over the images. With the use of `DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS` flags (in `drawKeypoints()`) for each  keypoint, the circle around keypoint with keypoint size and orientation will be drawn.

Comment: @Kornel Thanks for your clear explanation. Could I ask what exactly `class_id` represents. If I have ground truth image for semantic segmentation problem and if I extract `SIFT` features, if the key point is inside a specific object region, Can we assign the label of object to that keypoint through `class_id`?